# Concatenate string array in Kotlin from data class

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a data `Class` like

```
data class Data(val string: String, val state: Boolean)
```

and that class is an array like

```
val data = ArrayList<Data>()
data.add(Data("String 1", false)
data.add(Data("String 2", true)
data.add(Data("String 3", true)
data.add(Data("String 4", false)
```

I need to concatenate only `true` strings like

```
val result = "String 2;String 3"
```

I took a look at `joinToString()` method, but no idea how to deal with in this case. One more thing is that, I need to get those concatenated strings later back as Array.

How optimal achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something as simple as this :

```
        val result = data.asSequence()
           .filter(Data::state)
           .map(Data::string)
           .joinToString(separator = ";")
```

Result :

`String 2;String 3`

Then :

`result.split(";")`

Comment: No problem, its worth noting when iterating over any collection `asSequence` transforms it into a `Sequence` and is lazily collected on the terminal result, rather than just collection which eagerly collects on every transformation or operater. Seqience in many respects is akin to the Java stream api.

Answer (score 4):

First, you need to filter your list. And then you can use joinToString method.

```
val result : String = data.filter { it.state }.joinToString(seperator = ";") { it.string }
```

After that you can convert the string to list of strings like this :

```
val list = result.split(";")
```